# Htaccess redirect url [add a part]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect:

```
http://www.domain.com/?id=123456

to

http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=123456
```

with htaccess and mod_rewrite

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try and see how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(.+)
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: My fault. Edited, give that a try.